# Question about electric fields in atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I'm reading something that talks about the ideal construction of an atom(Aufbau), and it says '' For the ideal construction of an atom, imagine an atom of nucleus of charge +1, inside its electric field add an electron, forming like this the atom of atomic number 1''
Notice that this was translated and it might not be perfect.

Now my question. How could an atom of charge +1 without electrons form an electric field?

Comment: The nucleus has a positive charge. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, if the atom is made only of one proton and it has no electrons can it form an electric field?

Comment: The proton has a positive charge, the electron a negative charge. The hydrogen atom is neutral.

Comment: Yes, but the problem was that it had an electric field before the electron was added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could an atom of charge +1 without electrons form an electric field?

A single, stationary positive charge $q$ has an electric field around it that varies with distance $\mathbf r$ from the charge as determined by [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Electric_field)

$$\mathbf E(\mathbf r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat r$$

You do not need the presence of both a positive and negative charge in order to have an electric field; a single charge is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, I should probably review electric fields